# Proper use of random seeds in Jax

Tags: reinforcement-learning, random-seed, jax, dqn

I am using Jax for Reinforcement Learning with DQN. For a step in the environment, I am using two alternatives regarding the generation of random seeds. These two approaches lead to significantly different results. Why does this happen? Which approach aligns with the proper use of random seeds in Jax?

The first one is indicated by the [Jax documentation](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax-101/05-random-numbers.html):

```
rng, step_rng = jax.random.split(rng)
next_state, next_env_state, reward, terminated, info = env.step(step_rng, env_state, action.squeeze(), env_params)
```

The second one is according to an example of [purejaxrl](https://github.com/luchris429/purejaxrl/blob/main/examples/walkthrough.ipynb):

```
rng, _rng = jax.random.split(rng)
_rng, step_rng = jax.random.split(_rng)
next_state, next_env_state, reward, terminated, info = env.step(step_rng, env_state, action.squeeze(), env_params)
```

EDIT:
This is a short piece of code used in my environment step function, which makes a step in a subenvironment.

```
state, env_state, _, _, rng = runner
q = self.agent_nn.apply(self.agent_params, state)
action = jnp.argmax(q)
rng, rng_step = jax.random.split(rng)
next_state, next_env_state, reward, terminated, info = 
self.env.step(rng_step, env_state, action, self.env_params)
```

SECOND EDIT: use of random seed within lax.scan

```
def train(rng):

    rng, network_init_rng = jax.random.split(rng)
    network = q_network(env.action_space(env_params).n)
    init_x = jnp.zeros((1, config["STATE_SIZE"]))
    network_params = network.init(network_init_rng, init_x)
    
    training = TrainState.create(apply_fn=network.apply,
                                 params=network_params,
                                 target_params=network_params,
                                 tx=tx)

    rng, _rng = jax.random.split(rng)
    _rng, reset_rng = jax.random.split(_rng)
    state, env_state = env.reset(reset_rng, env_params)

    @jit
    @scan_tqdm(config["TOTAL_STEPS"])
    def _run_step(runner, i_step):

        training, env_state, state, rng, buffer_state, i_episode = runner

        rng, *_rng = jax.random.split(rng, 3)
        random_q_rng, random_number_rng = _rng

        q_state = network.apply(training.params, state)
        random_number = jax.random.uniform(random_number_rng, minval=0, maxval=1, shape=(1,))
        exploitation = jnp.greater(random_number, config["EPS"])
        action = jnp.where(exploitation, jnp.argmax(q_state, 1), random_action)

        rng, _rng = jax.random.split(rng)
        _rng, step_rng = jax.random.split(_rng)
        next_state, next_env_state, reward, terminated, info = env.step(step_rng, env_state, action.squeeze(), env_params)
        
        return runner

    rng, _rng = jax.random.split(rng)
    runner = (training, env_state, state, _rng, buffer_state, 0)
    runner, metrics = lax.scan(_run_step, runner, jnp.arange(config["TOTAL_STEPS"]), config["TOTAL_STEPS"])

    return {"runner": runner}
```

Comment: Both of these look fine in isolation, but to answer the question of whether it’s proper use, I’d want to see the greater context where this code appears.

Comment: One of my implementations of random seeds  is a DDQN scheme, similar to the PPO application of purejaxrl (link in question). I hope that if you can give me some guidance based on this, it will work for my code.

Another implementation is within the environment step function, which performs a step in a sub-environment. The code has been appended to the question.

Comment: Again, this looks fine in isolation. The only issue would be if you re-use the same key multiple times, which cannot be determined from this isolated snippet.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help with my vague question. I have added a piece of my script in the question, where you can see three instances of random seed use, two of them within a lax.scan function. Does this addition offer the necessary context?

Comment: I don't see any problems with that script, but there doesn't appear to be any need for the line `_rng, step_rng = jax.random.split(_rng)` because `_rng` is not referenced subsequently. You could replace that with `step_rng = _rng` without causing prng independence issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, why do I get considerably different results with each of the alternatives I presented in the question? I understand that the two approaches use the same base key `rng`, but in different ways. Could this difference be just a product of uncertainty and not a problem of my code?

Comment: You get different results because you're drawing different random samples, the same as if you started with a different random seed.

Comment: That's what I thought! Thank you for your help.